# Docker support for the new kernel

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, docker

I have installed new kernel to my ubuntu system 3.10.92 version, then I have installed docker support for it. once I start pulling some images it shows error saying that:

```
root@ubuntu:/# docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Then I have started the daemon process, as

```
root@ubuntu:/# docker daemon &
[1] 9634
root@ubuntu:/# INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "aufs" failed: driver not supported 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

What should be done in order to start the docker for this kernel?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, or about a program you created, so it is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help at [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running? See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15651#issuecomment-136491658

Comment: @ VonC version is 14.04